# Fail to log in Ubuntu for deleting my home folder

Tags: command-line, files, directory, home-directory

I moved my home folder("huangzhiwu") to `/usr/share` carelessly. Then after i noticed that ,i make  a new folder named huangzhiwu in `/home` ,and moved all files from `/usr/share/huangzhiwu` to the new home folder `/home/huangzhiwu`. but when i log in again, it failed,that means i cannot log in. What should i do? Thank you for help!

Comment: I try to type command: chown -R huangzhiwu:huangzhiwu /home/huangzhiwu in safe mode as root, but still to fail to log in ubuntu. I fell so silly, why shuld i delete that! So really hope some one to help me

Answer (score 2):

What happens exactly when you try to login?

Try:

```
ls -als /usr/share/huangzhiwu
```

are there any .files ?

move them also

```
sudo mv /usr/share/huangzhiwu/* /home/huangzhiwu/
```

then do:

```
cd /home/huangzhiwu

find -type d -exec sudo chmod 755 '{}' \;
find -type f -exec sudo chmod 766 '{}' \;
sudo rm .Xauthority
cd .. && sudo chmod 755 huangzhiwu
```

you may also try:

```
cd /tmp && sudo rm -r .X*
```

Comment: yeah, i login but iy return  to the login windows quickly, i am to try your method， thank you,catalesia. and there are still all my files in /home/huangzhiwu, not missed

Comment: ehem, are there more users in the home folder? the find command I wrote will change all users privileges. best do cd /home/huangzhiwu  I edited the answer

Comment: Still fail. I find there are no unvisible files in my home folder. Only Doucments,Music,etc folders. Wuwu。。。

Comment: what happens when you do `ls -als /usr/share/huangzhiwu`